# Docker - dotnet - can't run app from entrypoint

Tags: .net, docker, .net-core, command-line-interface

I have weird problems with entrypoint in my dockerfile.

This is my dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:latest

WORKDIR /test

ADD . /test

RUN ["dotnet", "restore", "DockerAPI2.sln"]
RUN ["dotnet", "build", "DockerAPI2.sln"]

EXPOSE 4000/tcp

ENTRYPOINT [ "dotnet", "DockerAPI2.dll" ]
```

When I run docker run --name test -d -p 4001:4000 `-v "C:\Users\random\docker":"/var/lib" -t test-img:latest`
I get next error:

> No executable found matching command "dotnet-DockerAPI2.dll

What I noticed is that for some xy reason, he is placing "-" between dotnet and DockerAPI2.dll which is ofc not valid. I would like to know if this is a bug or there is some way to get around this?

PS: I am running Docker for Windows with Linux containers, and I have enabled 4001 in firewall.

Comment: Does `dotnet build …` create `DockerAPI2.dll` create in `/test`, but not in some subdirectory of it? Try to use absolute full path instead.

Comment: Yes dotnet build creates dll. I've figure it out. It should contain full path of dll since dll is not in the /test folder, but in /test/DockerAPI2/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.0/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is pretty simple. I was looking in the directory of WORKDIR which is

> /test

, but I needed to look into path where actual dll is, and that is

> /test/DockerAPI2/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.0/

Comment: this does not make sense, your `DockerAPI2.dll` should be existed in `/test` after the `ADD . /test`. However looks like that should be added after building. Your simple dockerfile  should be used for already-built app so that you can just copy the built app to the image.

Answer (score 0):

You can try build -o /test
This shall redirect the output directory.